# how to read / write doc and excel file in android?

Tags: android

I am developing application similar to openoffice. I need to read/write doc ,excel , powerpoint files in this application . How can I do it ? Is there any android SDK classes for this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK does not include this functionality, because file structure of excel and word files is very complicated. There are a number of libraries available:

[smartoffice](https://artifex.com/products-smart-office-overview/)

[jWord](http://www.independentsoft.de/jword/index.html)

[jOpenDocument libraries](http://www.jopendocument.org/) (don't know if you can use this on android)

Comment: Is this library available for JAVA only ?

Comment: This is a java library, so it is available for java. But you can use this library for your android application as well...

Comment: Try Apache POI or the JExcelAPI for reading and writing Excel files.

Comment: How can you use this for android? Examples are based on java swing classes that are not available in android project, such as javax.swing.TableModel

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi did you find any solution for this problem? As I am not able to import javax.swing in my android code.