# How to read office documents in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read / write doc and excel file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790503/how-to-read-write-doc-and-excel-file-in-android)

I just need to read/view all microsoft office files such as word,powerpoint,excel documents in android.I've installed office document viewer in my device.I need any sample code to view those files.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link i think this is what you need [How to render PDF in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883355/how-to-render-pdf-in-android) its for pdf i think you can do same for office docs

you can send via intent if app is already installed or display in webview with google docs links